# What needs to be done for changing a Chrome Extension to manifest_version 2? My extension simply opens a url in a popup.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, eval

What is the alternative to eval() in his case?

```
<script>
function load() {

    var url = 'index.html';
    if(eval('('+localStorage['isprouser']+')') == true)
    url = 'index.html';

    window.location = url;
}
</script>
```

I guess this is not allowed.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are using `eval` here at all. Why would `if(localStorage['isprouser'] == true)` not work here? What type of value do you expect in `localStorage`?

Comment: Unless `localStorage` contains an expression, `eval` is not needed. And even if it is an expression, you should rewrite the code such that `eval` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the evel line with this:

```
localStorage.getItem('isprouser'])
```

and see if you are getting something...